# multiple headers on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm beginning to create project with Arabic and English language,
 I've created `header-en.php` for English pages and `header-ar.php` for Arabic pages.
 I asked this question before; the answer it was to use multiple header use this code:

```
$h = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'header_language', true);
if($h=='en'){
    get_header( 'en' );
}elseif($h=='ar'){
    get_header( 'ar' );
}else{
    get_header();
}
```

I've already paste this code to `page.php` but it didn't work,
 also I tried to use this code:

```
if ( is_home() ) :
    get_header( 'en' );
elseif ( is_404() ) :
    get_header( '404' );
else :
    get_header();
endif;
```

The second code that I tried its worked on the home page only, but what about pages created on the admin pages screen on WordPress and how to use page ID to get the `header-en.php` or `header-ar.php`?

So my first question how to use multiple headers and working on the pages id?

My second question is that found alternative for `page.php` and `index.php`?

Because I need to make home page for Arabic and home page for English..

Answer (score 1):

Try to use: `get_the_ID()` function

```
$get_pid= get_the_ID();

$h = get_post_meta($get_pid, 'header_language', true);
    if($h=='en'){
        get_header( 'en' );
    }elseif($h=='ar'){
        get_header( 'ar' );
    }else{
        get_header();
    }
```

Comment: not working, but I tried this code and worked with page id :
if ( is_home() ) :
 get_header( 'en' );
elseif ( is_page($id=19) ) :
 get_header( 'en' );
elseif ( is_page($id=32) ) :
 get_header( 'en' );
else :
 get_header();
endif;

Comment: what you got in $get_pid variable..and where are you execute your code...page.php or index.php?

Answer (score 0):

not working, but I tried this code and worked with pag id:
if ( is_home() ) :

```
get_header( 'en' );
```

elseif ( is_page($id=19) ) :

```
get_header( 'en' );
```

elseif ( is_page($id=32) ) :

```
get_header( 'en' );
```

else :

```
get_header();
```

endif;

thanks..